# Template function for splitting strings in C++

Tags: c++, strings, c++17

I'd like to write a function to split strings in C++ to check my template learning. I've also read some relavent questions in this site but most of them don't use templates or `string_view`. A related question in StackOverflow I asked is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50549688/whats-the-best-practices-for-designing-function-template-to-deal-with-string-ch).

My goal is to write a function such that:

1. The function can split `std::basic_string`, not only `std::string`.
2. The delimiter can be a `CharT`, or `const CharT* p` or `std::basic_string<CharT>`, multiple chars means the delimiter should be fully matched (like `str.split` in Python), not *any* of the chars.
3. The results are put into a sequence container from STL.
4. The user need not do any explicit conversion when parsing arguments, e.g. `std::string_view(some_str)`.
5. (Optional) The function can split `const CharT* p` or any string literals.

My major concerns are

1. To minimize the number of the functions need to be overloaded.
2. To write template codes in a more modern C++ way. (For example, I've learn a lot by reading `boost::algorithm::trim`, many generic functions work on *iterator ranges*. But the `boost` version of `split` seems a bit complicate for me right now.)
3. How `string_view` in C++17 can help in this example. My version seems not take full advantages of it.
4. How to design a better function signature of the *master* template to relieve the pain when writing overloading?

Below is my first attempt.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <string_view>
#include <vector>

template <typename CharT, typename ContainerT>
void split(
    std::basic_string_view<CharT> str,
    std::basic_string_view<CharT> delimiters,
    ContainerT &conts) {
    conts.clear();
    std::size_t start = 0, end;
    std::size_t len = delimiters.size();
    while ((end = str.find(delimiters, start)) !=
           std::basic_string_view<CharT>::npos) {
        if (end - start) {
            conts.emplace_back(str, start, end - start);
        }
        start = end + len;
    }

    if (start != std::basic_string_view<CharT>::npos && start < str.size()) {
        conts.emplace_back(str, start, str.size() - start);
    }
}

template <typename CharT, typename ContainerT>
void split(
    const std::basic_string<CharT> &str,
    const std::basic_string<CharT> &delimiters,
    ContainerT &conts) {
    split(
        std::basic_string_view<CharT>(str),
        std::basic_string_view<CharT>(delimiters), conts);
}

template <typename CharT, typename ContainerT>
void split(
    std::basic_string<CharT> str, const CharT *delimiter, ContainerT &conts) {
    split(
        std::basic_string_view<CharT>(str),
        std::basic_string_view<CharT>(delimiter), conts);
}

template <typename CharT, typename ContainerT>
void split(
    const std::basic_string<CharT> &str, CharT delimiter, ContainerT &conts) {
    split(
        std::basic_string_view<CharT>(str),
        std::basic_string_view<CharT>(&delimiter, 1), conts);
}

template <typename Iter>
void print(Iter begin, Iter end) {
    for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << "/";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::string str("haha,ha,,haha,,ha,,,ha,");
    std::vector<std::string> strs;

    split(std::string_view(str), std::string_view(","), strs);
    print(strs.begin(), strs.end());

    split(str, std::string(","), strs);
    print(strs.begin(), strs.end());

    split(str, ',', strs);
    print(strs.begin(), strs.end());

    split(str, ",,", strs);
    print(strs.begin(), strs.end());

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the formatting is peculiar — I can’t see where the function begins.

---

```
ContainerT &cont
const CharT *delimiter
```

The style in C++ is to put the `*` or `&` with the *type*, not the identifier.  This is called out specifically near the beginning of Stroustrup’s first book, and is an intentional difference from C style.

---

```
std::size_t start = 0, end;
  ⋮
while ((end = str.find(delimiters, start)) !=
       std::basic_string_view<CharT>::npos)
```

[⧺ES.10](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#es10-declare-one-name-only-per-declaration): Declare one name (only) per declaration.

Meanwhile, you *can* declare `end` just where it is needed, not ahead of time.

```
while (size_t end=str.find(delimiters, start); end != str.npos)
```

You can also make the clauses of the condition more readable by making the names short:  For example, see that I used the same instance `str` to get `npos` rather than its class name.

---

> The function can split `std::basic_string`, not only `std::string`.
>   How string_view in C++17 can help in this example. My version seems not take full advantages of it.

```
std::basic_string_view<CharT> str,
```

Your input argument `str` will be able to take `basic_string` of any character type, but only using the default `Traits`.  You might do that on purpose, if Traits are never used other than the defaults?

A `string_view` will take a `string_view`, `string`, or C-style lexical string.

> The delimiter can be a `CharT`, or `const CharT* p` or `std::basic_string<CharT>`

So this first form will take the latter two types, as well as `string_view`.  You do not need to overload to take `CharT delimiter` separately.

You do not need to overload to take `basic_string` for both parameters, because the `string_view` will take those!

So, two of the overloads should just be removed.  The last one, that takes a `CharT` delimiter, needs to take the `string_view` for `str` so it will handle different types for that — you have it taking a `basic_string` only, which will be inefficient (copied!) if passed a `const CharT*` or `string_view`.

---

```
template <typename CharT, typename ContainerT>
void split ( ⋯, ContainerT& conts)
```

Don’t use “out” parameters.  *Return* values ([⧺F.20](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#f20-for-out-output-values-prefer-return-values-to-output-parameters)).

I can see the appeal here of getting template argument deduction on the return value, but that does not make up for the lack of composibility.  You can add a default type to the `ContainerT` template parameter, which is handy for the case where the user doesn’t care.

```
template <typename CharT, typename ContainerT = vector<basic_string<CharT>>
ContainerT split ( ⋯ )
```

You *are* assuming that the container holds elements which have the form of constructor you are expecting.

Anyway, now your first example in `main` becomes:

```
auto strs = split (str, ",");
```

---

```
template <typename Iter>
void print(Iter begin, Iter end) {
    for (auto it = begin; it != end; ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << "/";
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


    print(strs.begin(), strs.end());
```

You should just take the container, not separate begin/end.  That not only makes passing easier, but makes the function easier too!

```
template <typename R>
void print(const R& rng) {
    for (const auto& item : rng) {
        std::cout << item << "/";
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}


    print(strs);
```

Oh, and don’t use `std::endl`.

---

I also should point out that it’s good practice how you have unit tests for your function!

Comment: Regarding your first point: While I get where you come from ("it is a type, it belongs together"), sadly, C++ declarations tend to advocate the other style for clarity. `int *a, b;` IMO expresses better that `b` is not of type `int*` than `int* a, b;`. (Yes, dedicated C++ programmers will know this tidbit, but it will come to surprise beginners or people switching between languages).

Comment: @hoffmale that is moot because you don’t put more than one declarator per statement.  `int* a= whatever; ⋯ int b = foo(a);`

Comment: I still have my first edition *C++ Programming Language* from 1987.  I’ll have to find the specific passages and post it somewhere.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reading my code. I agree with the format issue of my code since it was formatted using a mixed version of clang-format setting. I don't even know that declaration can happen in a `while` condition.

Comment: The remaining part that confuses me is that while `std::string_view` can receive `std::string` or `const char*` argument, `basic_string_view<T>` seems rejecting `basic_string<T>` or `const T*`. After a quick search it seems that implicit conversion is not allow when doing template deduction. So I still not clear about how to adapt the function signature. Or is it necessary (the only way) for one either explicitly specify template argument like `test<char>(str)` or manually wrap a string like `test(string_view(str));` to be able to call `void test(basic_string_view<T> str);` in this case?

Comment: I see — try adding a default to handle the common case:  `template <typename CharT=char> ⋯`

Comment: There is no `while` with an init-statement in the standard C++ yet.

Comment: Sorry; just use `for` instead of `while`, with the 3rd part empty.